# How to extract data while going on to the next pages and save it as a dataframe into a csv file? The code I am using gives output of only 1 page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I have gone through multiple posts and tried them but I haven't been able to solve this. I am unable to scrape 5000 pages of table from the website 'https://www.adelaide.edu.au/directory/atoz?dsn=directory.phonebook;orderby=last%2Cfirst%2Cposition_n;m=atoz;perpage=50;page=1'

I am using - 
urls = []
for n in pages:
    urls = url+n
    print(urls)

I have a website of around 5000+ pages and I need to extract table from everyone of these using python. In that table email is provided as a link which I have been able to scrape but I am failing to put all that in a dataframe and I am also not able to save the data of all the pages. The code I use reiterated the last page 5000 times instead

```
url = 'https://www.adelaide.edu.au/directory/atoz?dsn=directory.phonebook;orderby=last%2Cfirst%2Cposition_n;m=atoz;page=;perpage=50'

urls = []
for n in pages:
   urls = url+n
   print(urls)

def parse_url(url):
   response = requests.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
   return [(table['id'], parse_html_table(table)) for table in 
   soup.find_all('table')]

def parse_html_table(table):
   n_columns = 0
   n_rows = 0
   column_names = []

   column_names = [th.get_text() for th in table.select('th')]
   n_columns = len(column_names)

   rows = table.select('tr')[1:]
   n_rows = len(rows)

   df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names, index=range(n_rows))

   r_index = 0
   for row in rows:
       c_index = 0
       for cell in row.select('td'):
           if cell.get('data-th') == 'Email':
               anchor = cell.select_one('a')
               df.iat[r_index, c_index] = anchor.get('href').replace('mailto:', '') if anchor else cell.get_text()
           else:
               df.iat[r_index, c_index] = cell.get_text()
           c_index += 1
       r_index += 1

   return df
```

print(parse_url(url))

I need a csv file which saves the table including the email address in a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

it's reiterating over the same pages because `url = 'https://www.adelaide.edu.au/directory/atoz?dsn=directory.phonebook;orderby=last%2Cfirst%2Cposition_n;m=atoz;page=;perpage=50'`
 has `;page=` in it. Get rid of that and use a base url of `https://www.adelaide.edu.au/directory/atoz?dsn=directory.phonebook;orderby=last%2Cfirst%2Cposition_n;m=atoz;perpage=50;page=` and append on the page number from there. Now I don't know how you got your page numbers, but I just quickly set up to go trhough first 10 pages:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.adelaide.edu.au/directory/atoz?dsn=directory.phonebook;orderby=last%2Cfirst%2Cposition_n;m=atoz;perpage=50'


pages = list(range(1,11))

urls = []
for n in pages:
   urls.append(base_url+';page=%s' %n)


def parse_url(url):
   headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}
   response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
   return [(table['id'], parse_html_table(table)) for table in soup.find_all('table')]

def parse_html_table(table):
   n_columns = 0
   n_rows = 0
   column_names = []

   column_names = [th.get_text() for th in table.select('th')]
   n_columns = len(column_names)

   rows = table.select('tr')[1:]
   n_rows = len(rows)

   df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names, index=range(n_rows))

   r_index = 0
   for row in rows:
       c_index = 0
       for cell in row.select('td'):
           if cell.get('data-th') == 'Email':
               anchor = cell.select_one('a')
               df.iat[r_index, c_index] = anchor.get('href').replace('mailto:', '') if anchor else cell.get_text()
           else:
               df.iat[r_index, c_index] = cell.get_text()
           c_index += 1
       r_index += 1

   return df


results = pd.DataFrame()
for link in urls:
    temp_table = parse_url(link)[0][1]
    results = results.append(temp_table)
    print ('Appended: %s' %(link.split(';')[-1]))

results = results.reset_index(drop=True)
results.to_csv('path/to/filename.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
              Telephone                   ...                                                     Email
0   \n+61 8 8313 0548\n                   ...                          pragathi.sridhar@adelaide.edu.au
1   \nnone registered\n                   ...                                     priya@adelaide.edu.au
2   \n+61 8 8313 9161\n                   ...                          ehsan.abbasnejad@adelaide.edu.au
3   \n+61 8 8313 2617\n                   ...                             claire.abbott@adelaide.edu.au
4   \n+61 8 8313 1977\n                   ...                             claire.abbott@adelaide.edu.au
5   \n+61 8 8313 5748\n                   ...                           dabbott@eleceng.adelaide.edu.au
6   \n+61 8 8313 1244\n                   ...                                kym.abbott@adelaide.edu.au
7   \n+61 8 8313 1250\n                   ...                                sam.abbott@adelaide.edu.au
8   \nnone registered\n                   ...                          ingy.abdelshafei@adelaide.edu.au
9   \n+61 8 8313 0590\n                   ...                          adila.abdulhalim@adelaide.edu.au
10  \n+61 8 8313 3186\n                   ...                         suraya.abdulhalim@adelaide.edu.au
11  \n+61 8 8313 8245\n                   ...                    muslihudeen.abdul-aziz@adelaide.edu.au
12  \n+61 8 8313 6024\n                   ...                            farhana.abedin@adelaide.edu.au
13  \n+61 8 8313 4729\n                   ...                     alireza.abedinvaramin@adelaide.edu.au
14  \n+61 8 8313 4652\n                   ...                                 amy.abela@adelaide.edu.au
15  \n+61 8 8313 5652\n                   ...                              andrew.abell@adelaide.edu.au
16  \nnone registered\n                   ...                              curtis.abell@adelaide.edu.au
17  \n+61 8 8313 7245\n                   ...                               amanda.able@adelaide.edu.au
18  \n+61 8 8313 7075\n                   ...                                jason.able@adelaide.edu.au
19  \n+61 8 8313 4849\n                   ...                             sareh.abooali@adelaide.adu.au
20  \n+61 8 8313 2132\n                   ...                         natalie.aboustate@adelaide.edu.au
21  \n+61 8 8313 6965\n                   ...                             maria.abraham@adelaide.edu.au
22  \n+61 8 8313 1999\n                   ...                              nori.acevedo@adelaide.edu.au
23  \n+61 8 8313 9284\n                   ...                               adam.davies@adelaide.edu.au
24  \n+61 8 8313 7634\n                   ...                             jackson.adams@adelaide.edu.au
25  \nnone registered\n                   ...                               jerry.adams@adelaide.edu.au
26  \n+61 8 8313 0714\n                   ...                                nico.adams@adelaide.edu.au
27  \n+61 8 8222 7413\n                   ...                              robert.adams@adelaide.edu.au
28  \n+61 8 8313 0197\n                   ...                                         none registered\n
29  \n+61 8 8313 4988\n                   ...                             brenda.adcock@adelaide.edu.au
..                  ...                   ...                                                       ...
20  \n+61 8 8313 1111\n                   ...                             vicki.bogucki@adelaide.edu.au
21  \n+61 8 8313 1673\n                   ...                         jessica.bohorquez@adelaide.edu.au
22  \n+61 8 8313 4729\n                   ...                           mahmoud.bokhari@adelaide.edu.au
23  \n+61 8 8313 6530\n                   ...                             anthelia.bond@adelaide.edu.au
24  \n+61 8 8313 0771\n                   ...                               nicole.bond@adelaide.edu.au
25  \n+61 8 8313 0277\n                   ...                                rosie.bond@adelaide.edu.au
26  \n+61 8 8222 3504\n                   ...                           claudine.bonder@adelaide.edu.au
27  \n+61 8 8313 5340\n                   ...                                 faye.bone@adelaide.edu.au
28  \n+61 8 8313 4655\n                   ...                           jennifer.bonham@adelaide.edu.au
29  \n+61 8 8313 7478\n                   ...                              wendy.bonner@adelaide.edu.au
30  \n+61 8 8313 6722\n                   ...                          mohammad.bonyadi@adelaide.edu.au
31  \n+61 8 8313 9840\n                   ...                         edenleah.bonython@adelaide.edu.au
32  \n+61 8 8311 7241\n                   ...                           bernadette.boog@adelaide.edu.au
33  \n+61 8 8313 3090\n                   ...                              grant.booker@adelaide.edu.au
34  \n+61 8 8313 3080\n                   ...                            sara.borazjani@adelaide.edu.au
35  \n+61 8 8313 4925\n                   ...                               goran.boren@adelaide.edu.au
36  \n+61 8 8313 1549\n                   ...                            jeffrey.borgas@adelaide.edu.au
37  \nnone registered\n                   ...                          ashlee.borgkvist@adelaide.edu.au
38  \n+61 8 8313 7162\n                   ...                                     chana@adelaide.edu.au
39  \n+61 8 8313 9832\n                   ...                            sheryl.borland@adelaide.edu.au
40  \n+61 8 8313 6432\n                   ...                             kerry.bormann@adelaide.edu.au
41  \nnone registered\n                   ...                               jane.boroky@adelaide.edu.au
42  \n+61 8 8161 8116\n                   ...                           christina.boros@adelaide.edu.au
43  \n+61 8 8313 6307\n                   ...                           sandra.borrelli@adelaide.edu.au
44  \n+61 8 8313 4456\n                   ...                              kate.borrett@adelaide.edu.au
45  \n+61 8 8313 6665\n                   ...                            jayakumar.bose@adelaide.edu.au
46  \n+61 8 8313 3492\n                   ...                             john.bosnakis@adelaide.edu.au
47  \n+61 8 8313 7641\n                   ...                           cynthia.bottema@adelaide.edu.au
48  \n+61 8 8313 5436\n                   ...                              james.botten@adelaide.edu.au
49  \n+61 8 8313 5878\n                   ...                            paul.botterill@adelaide.edu.au

[500 rows x 5 columns]
```